# Linear independency of a group of vectors with one defined as a linear combination of the others

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a group of vectors $A = \{\,a_1,a_2,a_3,…a_k\,\}$ that are linearly dependent in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $k\ge2$, and with $a_1$ being a linear combination of $\{\,a_2,a_3,…a_k\,\}$, does that imply that the remaining set of $\{\,a_2,a_3,…a_k\,\}$ is linearly independent?

Answer (score 2):

No. Take $n=2, k=3$ and

$a_1=(1,0), a_2=(2,0)$ and $a_3=(3,0)$.